# How to "Un-Normalise Data"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, normal-distribution

Hello how would I get the value back after I normalise the data ?

Currently I am taking my list of numbers and doing
$\frac{\text{Val} - \text{Min}}{\text{Max} - \text{Min}}$ on each of the numbers.
With gives me a number from $1$ to $0$;
But how would i revert this back to the original. I have tried 
$(\text{Val} + \text{Min}) \cdot (\text{Max} + \text{Min})$
this is probably really simple but I have become unstuck en and it kind of annoying me now.

Comment: val*(max-min)+min

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply each number in your list by $(\max-\min)$ and then add min to it. :)

Comment: O okay thank you i have solved it. Much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. And welcome to MSE! Hope we can still help you in the future.

Comment: $$ \begin{align} & \max\text{-}\min \\ & \max - \min \end{align} $$ $+1. \quad$ However, your minus sign looked like a hyphen (as in the first line above) rather than like a minus sign, so I edited your answer to correct that. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you, now the answer looks neat!